# Phonegap GPS using old cached positions

Tags: caching, jquery-mobile, cordova, gps

Does anyone know how to clear old, cached GPS positions in phonegap? I have an application that is using watchPosition to get a few position and then is transmitting the most accurate position but it often takes a position for hours earlier even though the maximumAge is set to 5000 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the returned Position from watchPosition you should check the Postion.timestamp to see if it is older than your threshold. If it is then you should just throw that result away.

However, you may have found a bug. What platform is this on?

Comment: Phonegap.0.9.5 running on android 2.2.1

Comment: Yeah, that is using the native geolocation feature of Android so you'll have to raise a bug against Android. Probably just as easy to throw away the first bad result though.